# Why does the Java API use int instead of short or byte?

Tags: optimization, types, java

Why does the Java API use `int`, when `short` or even `byte` would be sufficient?

Example: The [`DAY_OF_WEEK`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) field in class [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) uses `int`.

If the difference is too minimal, then why do those datatypes (`short`, `int`) exist at all?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Some of the reasons have already been pointed out. For example, the fact that [*"...(Almost) All operations on byte, short will promote these primitives to int"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27122853/3182664). However, the obvious next question would be: **WHY** are these types promoted to `int`?

So to go one level deeper: The answer may simply be related to the Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set. As summarized in the [Table in the Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1), **all** integral arithmetic operations, like adding, dividing and others, are only available for the type `int` and the type `long`, and **not** for the smaller types.

<sub>(An aside: The smaller types (`byte` and `short`) are basically only intended for *arrays*. An *array* like `new byte[1000]` will take 1000 bytes, and an array like `new int[1000]` will take 4000 bytes)</sub>

Now, of course, one could say that *"...the obvious next question would be: **WHY** are these instructions only offered for `int` (and `long`)?"*.

One reason is mentioned in the JVM Spec mentioned above:

> If each typed instruction supported all of the Java Virtual Machine's run-time data types, there would be more instructions than could be represented in a byte

Additionally, the Java Virtual Machine can be considered as an abstraction of a real processor. And introducing dedicated [Arithmetic Logic Unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) for smaller types would not be worth the effort: It would need additional transistors, but it still could only execute one addition in one clock cycle. The dominant architecture when the JVM was designed was 32bits, just right for a 32bit `int`. (The operations that involve a 64bit `long` value are implemented as a special case).

<sub>(Note: The last paragraph is a bit oversimplified, considering possible vectorization etc., but should give the basic idea without diving too deep into processor design topics)</sub>

---

EDIT: A short addendum, focussing on the example from the question, but in an more general sense: One could also ask whether it would not be beneficial to store *fields* using the smaller types. For example, one might think that memory could be saved by storing `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` as a `byte`. But here, the Java Class File Format comes into play: All the [Fields in a Class File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.5) occupy at least one "slot", which has the size of one `int` (32 bits). (The "wide" fields, `double` and `long`, occupy two slots). So explicitly declaring a field as `short` or `byte` would not save any memory either.

Comment: I would guess that the logic to why operands are promoted to int is also related to the rationale used in [C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24372323/1708801)

Comment: @Marco13 "So explicitly declaring a field as short or byte would not save any memory either." is that true? I don't think that's correct.

Comment: @ACV Strictly speaking, an implementation could chose to store a more compact form, but the format that is exposed "virtually" (i.e. by the virtual machine) will treat the values as having at least the size of `int`. If you have a reference to another implementation, I'd update the answer and insert the link accordingly.

Answer (score 43):

(Almost) All operations on `byte`, `short` will promote them to `int`, for example, you cannot write:

```
short x = 1;
short y = 2;

short z = x + y; //error
```

Arithmetics are easier and straightforward when using `int`, no need to cast.

In terms of space, it makes a *very* little difference. `byte` and `short` would complicate things, I don't think  this micro optimization worth it since we are talking about a fixed amount of variables.

`byte` is relevant and useful when you program for embedded devices or dealing with files/networks. Also these primitives are limited, what if the calculations might exceed their limits in the future? Try to think about an extension for `Calendar` class that might evolve bigger numbers.

Also note that in a 64-bit processors, locals will be saved in registers and won't use any resources, so using `int`, `short` and other primitives won't make any difference at all. Moreover, many Java implementations align variables<sup>*</sup> (and objects).

---

<sup>*</sup> `byte` and `short` occupy the same space as `int` if they are *local* variables, *class* variables or even *instance* variables. Why? Because in (most) computer systems, variables  addresses are *aligned*, so for example if you use a single byte, you'll actually end up with two bytes - one for the variable itself and another for the padding.

On the other hand, in arrays, `byte` take 1 byte, `short` take 2 bytes and `int` take four bytes, because in arrays only the start and maybe the end of it has to be aligned. This will make a difference in case you want to use, for example, `System.arraycopy()`, then you'll really note a performance difference.

Comment: Fun fact: If you use final modifiers for both values, it will work. :)

Comment: @alexander why?

Comment: @elect In this case, the compiler can be sure that their sum is a valid `short`.

Answer (score 9):

Because arithmetic operations are easier when using integers compared to shorts. Assume that the constants were indeed modeled by `short` values. Then you would have to use the API in this manner:

```
short month = Calendar.JUNE;
month = month + (short) 1; // is july
```

Notice the explicit casting. Short values are implicitly promoted to `int` values when they are used in arithmetic operations. (On the operand stack, shorts are even expressed as ints.) This would be quite cumbersome to use which is why `int` values are often preferred for constants.

Compared to that, the gain in storage efficiency is minimal because there only exists a fixed number of such constants. We are talking about 40 constants. Changing their storage from `int` to `short` would safe you `40 * 16 bit = 80 byte`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531235/in-java-is-it-more-efficient-to-use-byte-or-short-instead-of-int-and-float-inst/14532302#14532302) for further reference.

Answer (score 5):

If you used the philosophy where integral constants are stored in the smallest type that they fit in, then Java would have a serious problem: whenever programmers write code using integral constants, they have to pay careful attention to their code to check if the type of the constants matter, and if so look up the type in the documentation and/or do whatever type conversions are needed.

So now that we've outlined a serious problem, what benefits could you hope to achieve with that philosophy? I would be unsurprised if the *only* runtime-observable effect of that change would be what type you get when you look the constant up via reflection. (and, of course, whatever errors are introduced by lazy/unwitting programmers not correctly accounting for the types of the constants)

Weighing the pros and the cons is very easy: it's a bad philosophy.

Answer (score 5):

The design complexity of a virtual machine is a function of how many kinds of operations it can perform.  It's easier to having four implementations of an instruction like "multiply"--one each for 32-bit integer, 64-bit integer, 32-bit floating-point, and 64-bit floating-point--than to have, in addition to the above, versions for the smaller numerical types as well.  A more interesting design question is why there should be four types, rather than fewer (performing all integer computations with 64-bit integers and/or doing all floating-point computations with 64-bit floating-point values).  The reason for using 32-bit integers is that Java was expected to run on many platforms where 32-bit types could be acted upon just as quickly as 16-bit or 8-bit types, but operations on 64-bit types would be noticeably slower.  Even on platforms where 16-bit types would be faster to work with, the extra cost of working with 32-bit quantities would be offset by the simplicity afforded by *only* having 32-bit types.

As for performing floating-point computations on 32-bit values, the advantages are a bit less clear.  There are some platforms where a computation like `float a=b+c+d;` could be performed most quickly by converting all operands to a higher-precision type, adding them, and then converting the result back to a 32-bit floating-point number for storage.  There are other platforms where it would be more efficient to perform all computations using 32-bit floating-point values.  The creators of Java decided that all platforms should be required to do things the same way, and that they should favor the hardware platforms for which 32-bit floating-point computations are faster than longer ones, even though this severely degraded PC both the speed and precision of floating-point math on a typical PC, as well as on many machines without floating-point units.  Note, btw, that depending upon the values of b, c, and d, using higher-precision intermediate computations when computing expressions like the aforementioned `float a=b+c+d;` will sometimes yield results which are significantly more accurate than would be achieved of all intermediate operands were computed at `float` precision, but will sometimes yield a value which is a tiny bit less accurate.  In any case, Sun decided everything should be done the same way, and they opted for using minimal-precision `float` values.

Note that the primary advantages of smaller data types become apparent when large numbers of them are stored together in an array; even if there were no advantage to having individual variables of types smaller than 64-bits, it's worthwhile to have arrays which can store smaller values more compactly; having a local variable be a `byte` rather than an `long` saves seven bytes; having an array of 1,000,000 numbers hold each number as a `byte` rather than a `long` waves 7,000,000 bytes.  Since each array type only needs to support a few operations (most notably read one item, store one item, copy a range of items within an array, or copy a range of items from one array to another), the added complexity of having more array types is not as severe as the complexity of having more types of directly-usable discrete numerical values.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there'd be a small advantage. If you have a

```
class MyTimeAndDayOfWeek {
    byte dayOfWeek;
    byte hour;
    byte minute;
    byte second;
}
```

then on a typical JVM it needs as much space as a class containing a single `int`. The memory consumption gets rounded to a next multiple of 8 or 16 bytes (IIRC, that's configurable), so the cases when there are real saving are rather rare.

This class would be slightly easier to use if the corresponding `Calendar` methods returned a `byte`. But there are no such `Calendar` methods, only `get(int)` which must returns an `int` because of other fields. Each operation on smaller types promotes to `int`, so you need a lot of casting.

Most probably, you'll either give up and switch to an `int` or write setters like

```
void setDayOfWeek(int dayOfWeek) {
    this.dayOfWeek = checkedCastToByte(dayOfWeek);
}
```

Then the type of `DAY_OF_WEEK` doesn't matter, anyway.

Comment: I doubt that the values will be packed like that, due to the severe performance penalty of non-aligned memory access on modern processors. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491578/whats-the-actual-effect-of-successful-unaligned-accesses-on-x86 for details

Answer (score 2):

Using variables smaller than the bus size of the CPU means more cycles are necessary. For example when updating a single byte in memory, a 64-bit CPU needs to read a whole 64-bit word, modify only the changed part, then write back the result.

Also, using a smaller data type requires overhead when the variable is stored in a register, since the behavior of the smaller data type to be accounted for explicitly. Since the whole register is used anyways, there is nothing to be gained by using a smaller data type for method parameters and local variables.

Nevertheless, these data types might be useful for representing data structures that require specific widths, such as network packets, or for saving space in large arrays, sacrificing speed.

Comment: very interesting stuff! +1 still I think those are optimizations which should be done by the JVM. I, as a developer, should only worry about the operations I want to perform on the type, semantic value it gives, and the range of values it provides.

Comment: @WilliMentzel Even semantically using `Byte` for day of month is not necesary, since what is means to the compiler is "please add special behavior to ensure overflow at 255", not "just a heads up, this value is very small". The simplest type is not always the most constrained one. I once had a discussion with a very nice coworker about whether it is better to use `Set` or `List` if you know the elements are distinct anyways, that ran along the same lines ;-)