# Is byte, short, char automatically promoted in switch statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement, type-promotion

Given the following code, is ***'a'*** (that is of type **char**) automatically promoted to int type in **switch-case** statement?

```
void testSwitch(byte x) {
    switch(x) {
       case 'a':   // 1
       case 256:   // 2
       default:   //  3
       case 1:    //  4
    }
```

}

I couldn't find whether Java SE7 mentions about that..

Thanks in advance for clarification.

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: switch takes an `int` and byte, char, and short can be automatically widened whenever needed.

Comment: [the type of `0`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-lang-fans/0zGzPygyJSU)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what the language specification mentions about this. See [this section on `switch` statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> Given a `switch` statement, all of the following must be true or a compile-time error occurs:
>
> - Every case constant associated with the `switch` statement must be assignment compatible with the type of the `switch` statement's *Expression* (§5.2).
> - ...

which means that a narrowing conversion will apply to the `char` value `'a'`. Its numeric value of `97` is representable as a `byte`. The value `256` however does not fit so the compiler will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks @AR.3. Good clarification. It is a point worth remembering  :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the switch statement will generate tableswitch or lookupswitch primitives with constants which are promoted to int generally according to this

http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JavaCodeToByteCode_PartOne.html

[Why does the Java API use int instead of short or byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122610/why-does-the-java-api-use-int-instead-of-short-or-byte)