# Default type for primitive Java

Tags: java, jvm

I have a question about Java Primitive.

Is there some reason as to why the default type in java for the `Integer` primitive is int and not for example a `short` or `byte` ?

For example if I write

```
byte b = 10;
```

the literal 10 is a int for the compiler. Why is that?

Does anyone know I indicate where to find the answer? I also searched the JSL but I found nothing...

Comment: There are no "short" or "byte" literals: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1

Comment: Because a number without a specific character is a int, meaning that the JVM will use 4byte to store it. If you write a "long value" without a letter L, the JVM won't accept it since it is to long (long, ahah ;) ).

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @a_horse_with_no_name [Chapter 3. Lexical Structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html) describes [Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1). Quote:

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII
>   letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

The official doc says: 
`

byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement **integer**.

short: The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement **integer**. 
`

See the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: ok and why is the default primitive int and not byte or short?

Comment: Ok, I know but because it was just chosen as the default int?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122610/why-does-the-java-api-use-int-instead-of-short-or-byte