# Implicit conversion (or lack thereof) of a char to an int

Tags: java

I was studying for my OCA exam and came across this problem from Mala Gupta:

> ```
> class Course {
>     void enroll(long duration) {
>         System.out.println("long");
>     }
>     void enroll(int duration) {
>         System.out.println("int");
>     }
>     void enroll(String s) {
>         System.out.println("String");
>     }
>     void enroll(Object o) {
>         System.out.println("Object");
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> What is the output of the following code?
>
> ```
> class EJavaGuru {
>     public static void main(String args[]) {
>         Course course = new Course();
>         char c = 10;
>         course.enroll(c);
>         course.enroll("Object");
>     }
> }
>
> a. Compilation error 
> b. Runtime exception
> c. int 
>    String
> d. long 
>    Object
> ```

The correct answer is (c), which I validated as well after running the code. However, why does the `char` datatype get widened to an `int` in the method call?

According to my knowledge of implicit conversion of datatypes in Java, a `char` is not implicitly converted into an `int` by default.

TL;DR: Why does the following code not work

```
int x = 5;
char c;
c = x; // Compliation error here
```

But this works:

```
static void intParameterMethod( int someInt ) {}
public static void main( String args[] ) {
    char c = 5;
    intParameterMethod( c ); // No compilation error here
}
```

Comment: You can fit a char into an int. You may not be able to fit an int into a char.

Comment: Ahh ok. My bad, stupid question. Should have checked that before posting. Thanks for helping me out :D Please submit your comment as an answer so that I can mark it correct.

Comment: The 'mechanic' behind this is called *widening*. A `char` can be widened into an `int`. The full list of widenings for primitives can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122610/why-does-the-java-api-use-int-instead-of-short-or-byte/27122853#27122853

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb No worries. All of this stuff can be found in the JLS--while not an exciting read (most of the time), pretty much all Java behavior is explained, if not always defended, within.