# JAVA cannot convert from int to short

Tags: java, int, short

Hi I am new one here and this is my first question:
I have a code with simple aritmetic operator.
But it won't works:

```
int a = 10;
short premennaTypuShort = (short)a;     /*retyped variable a into short type and entered into new variable*/
premennaTypuShort = premennaTypuShort - 7;
/*now i am trying to decrease the number but eclipse wrote that cannot convert from int to short.*/
```

i am trying to decrease the number specified as short but eclipse wrote that cannot convert from int to short. I don't undertand why.
so where is the problem ? how can I repair this error?

Comment: Whenever dealing with short and int arithmetic operations java return result in `int` so you have to typecast that into `int`

Comment: `premennaTypuShort -= 7;`

Comment: typecast that into `short` not in `int` sorry for typo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294934/setting-short-value-java?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 5):

java is 32 bit. That means that whenever any arithmetic operation is performed it will return in 32 bit value. So, you must cast it to short again, like so:

```
int a = 10;
short premennaTypuShort = (short)a;    
premennaTypuShort =(short)(premennaTypuShort - 7);
```

Comment: aha ... :) that second part 
premennaTypuShort =(short)(premennaTypuShort - 7);
I didn't know that another (short) is necesssary... why another? it was defined as short in first line. isn't it?

Comment: dear when result will come in integer then it reqiurd to convert in short otherwise precision loss

Comment: not sure why you mention unicode in your answer though.

Comment: unicode means java work on all available  character in world by define unicode so that in java integer is 4 bit but in C,C++ 2 bit

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in order to calculate `premennaTypuShort - 7`, `premennaTypuShort` first needs to be converted to an `int`, so the result of the calculation is an `int`.

This, in turn, means that you are then trying to assign an `int` back to a `short` variable, which requires an explicit downcast on your part.

Comment: thx for quick reply. -yes I am trying to do this aritmetical in short type. not integer. because I want the result in short type as well. 
how to do this explicit downcast?

Comment: Normally you would do this by downcasting the `7`, like this: `premennaTypuShort - (short)7`.  But afaik, Java doesn't ever perform `short` arithmetic.  It will always upcast `short`s to `int` to perform the arithmetic.  So you have to be content with the calculation being done with `int` arithmetic, and you then have to explicitly downcast the result to `short`.

Comment: ahaa.. i understand now .. any kind of aritmetic is done as integer and therefore if i want the result into short i need to type this 
premennaTypuShort =(short)(premennaTypuShort - 7);

Comment: Well, it can also do `long` arithmetic, so it's not like it can only do `int` arithmetic. But it won't do smaller than `int`, yes.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using a `byte`, a `short` or a `char` to perform arithmetic operations involving `ints`, there is an automatic promotion to the `int` primitive type.

Here, you're trying to assign an `int` back to a `short`.

A solution would be the assignment operator `-=`, this will avoid the conversion to an `int`

```
int a = 10;
short premennaTypuShort = (short)a; 
premennaTypuShort-=7;
System.out.println(premennaTypuShort); // 3
```

---

### WARNING

The assignment operator has a bad side too. Look at the following code.

```
short s = Short.MAX_VALUE;
s+=1;
System.out.println(s); // -32768
```

By adding `1` to Short.MAX_VALUE (`32767`), you're overflowing the short and will get unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

Additive operators (+ and -) are "Numerical Integer Operator". And Numerical Integer Operators always produce a value of type int or long.
Because, any integer operator except shift operator that has at least 1 operand which is of type long is carried out using 64 bit precision and the result would be of type long.
Otherwise the operation is carried out using 32 bit precision and the result would be of type int.
That is why here the expression `premennaTypuShort – 7` is producing a result of type `int` and to store an `int` value to a `short` you need to specifically cast it to `short` like following, which is known as narrowing.

```
premennaTypuShort = (short)(premennaTypuShort - 7)
```